# fetch invoices from quickbooks desktop with c# desktop

Tags: c#, quickbooks, invoice

hi i am working on a program with c# that fetch all invoices from quickbooks company file, any ideas...
i tried this code but i am not developping a web app

```
public ActionResult GetAllInvoice()
{
  List<Invoice> InvoiceList = new List<Invoice>();
  try
  {
    OAuth2RequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuth2RequestValidator(Access_token);
    // Create a ServiceContext with Auth tokens and realmId
    ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext(RealmId, IntuitServicesType.QBO, oauthValidator);
    serviceContext.IppConfiguration.MinorVersion.Qbo = "23";
    serviceContext.IppConfiguration.BaseUrl.Qbo = QboBaseUrl;
    // Create a QuickBooks QueryService using ServiceContext
    QueryService<Invoice> querySvc = new QueryService<Invoice>(serviceContext);
    InvoiceList = querySvc.ExecuteIdsQuery("SELECT * FROM Invoice").ToList();
    return View(InvoiceList);
  }
  catch (IdsException ex)
  {
    return View(InvoiceList);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return View(InvoiceList);
  }
}
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?  What is your connections string?  See folowing : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138326/how-to-query-some-data-out-of-a-quickbook-qbw-file

Comment: Please post the errors you get. And your environment

Comment: The code you posted is for QuickBooks ONLINE, but your question says you're trying to query QuickBooks DESKTOP. Can you clarify which one is correct? They are two different platforms, with two _very_ different APIs.

Comment: i didnt find a code for the desktop one

Comment: Are you trying to connect to QuickBooks DESKTOP, or QuickBooks ONLINE?

Comment: quickbooks desktop